# Maximum Flow of Network is NOT unique

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

Look at image below:

[image]

I'm trying to find the maximum flow from S to T using ford fulkerson algorithm, But I'm getting two answers. one is 12 the other one 14.

The Answer Which returns 12:

```
s->a->d->t = 2
s->b->e->t = 3
s->b->g->t = 2
s->c->b->d->t =2
s->c->g->t = 3
```

Again another one which returns 12:

```
s->a->d->t =2
s->b->e->t =3
s->b->d->t =2
s->b->g->t =2
s->c->g->t =3
```

And The Answer which returns 14:

```
s->a->e->t =2
s->b->d->t =4
s->b->e->t =3
s->b->g->t =2
s->c->g->t =3
```

Why is it like this? Is it normal or Am I doing Something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you are searching for an augmenting flow you are allowed to:

1. Go forward along edges where flow is less than capacity
2. Go backwards along edges where flow is greater than 0

So in your first example you can add more flow by tracing the path:

```
s->b->d->a->e->t (add 2 flow)
```

Note that the portion d->a is going backwards along an edge that already has flow through it.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm#Algorithm):

> Notice that it can happen that a flow from v to u is allowed in the residual network, though disallowed in the original network: if f(u,v)>0 and c(v,u)=0 then c_f(v,u)=c(v,u)-f(v,u)=f(u,v)>0.

Once you have increased the flow along all possible augmenting paths the value of the maximum flow will always be the same value.  (Although note that there may be many different ways of achieving this value.)

Comment: Thank u peter, but What are those ARROWS? They are saying that I can only move forward not backward, If I add (s->b->d->a->e->t) to my chosen paths then flow will be 15 even not 14!!!

Comment: You can only add 2 flow because a->d only had 2 flow going through it.

Comment: The issue is that you need to find the augmenting flow on the residual network (see the wikipedia article) which is different to the original, in particular some edges become bidirectional.

Comment: After you apply the changes in this augmenting flow, note that the resulting flow will only have flow moving in the direction you want.  All we have done with d->a is to reduce the flow in that direction.

Comment: I saw this video to solve my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxyCzzUuXLo , Wikipedia link is very complex and I can not understand those formulas!!!

Comment: in that video shows that the flow is the smallest capacity of an edge in a path. If I add (s->b->d->a->e->t) in my first example at the end, the smallest capacity will be 3 which is on s->b and I must add it to the max flow and the answer will be 15. Here is what I'm not understanding :( And Why I can not add (s->b->d->a->e->t) to the third example which its answer is 14?

Comment: This [topcoder tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow) has a good explanation of how to use reverse edges.  I think that video is missing important details.